# JavaScript Heredoc? Escape Newline: JSLint Bad Escapement?

Tags: javascript, escaping, newline, jslint, heredoc

```
var wrapped_string = "shouldn't this\
work?"
```

[JSLint](http://www.jslint.com/) gives a bad escapement error.

How do we do heredoc in JavaScript then? I have a long HTML string.

Comment: JSLint has a lot of arbitrary rules with vague reasoning. In this case, it's probably that errors with multi-line strings are common and easily missed (because many languages allow new lines without escapes). Lint probable wants you to use `"shouldn't this\n" + [LF not allowed in SO comments] "work?";`

Answer (score 7):

I think the reason about why this is treated as an error is because this syntax extension was recently standardized on the [ECMAScript 5th Edition Specification](http://ecma262-5.com/ELS5_HTML.htm#Section_7.8.4).

Although is widely supported, on an ECMAScript 3 implementation (which is the most widely implementation available) you don't have any guarantee that it will work, or just cause an early `SyntaxError` exception.

Another reason some people argue to avoid it, is that if you have any other character that isn't a `LineTerminator` you will have a `SyntaxError`, even on an ECMAScript 5 implementation.

For example, if you had a space after the backslash, the code will produce an error, and is not easy to spot just by reading the code:

```
// works:
var str = "foo\
bar";

// an space after it, SyntaxError:
var str = "foo\ 
bar";
```

Answer (score 1):

JSLint hurts your feelings, nothing else, try and running it on jQuery to see that.

The escapement is fine when you have a ton of strings, I consider it cleaner than using a ton of `+`.

Answer (score 0):

You can enable ECMA5 syntax via jslint.yml. This will all escaping newlines.

es5:      true      # true if ECMAScript 5 syntax should be allowed